# How to count number characters in SQL Google SQL Workspace?

Tags: string, google-bigquery, count

Usually, I write a code with LEN to count characters and it works, and when I try to count characters like an ID, a float column it doesn't work. LEN is used just for strings, and not for float.

Which command I should use to count the number of characters from an ID

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest something like this.

```
length(cast ID as string) as ID_LENGTH
```

Please share more details if this doesn't help, and ideally an example of an ID you're trying to count the length of.